# Error 'module' object is not callable al insertar imagen con Reportlab

Tags: django, python-2.7, reportlab

puede ayudarme con el siguiente error:

Al momento de generar el pdf aparece este error:

> 'module' object is not callable

```
logo = "/var/www/app/modulo/MSP.png"
tbl_data0 = [[Image(logo, width=80, height=45, hAlign='LEFT')]]
tbl_titu = Table(tbl_data0)
Story.append(tbl)
```

Python 2.7,
Django 1.8,
Reportlab.